# How to edit the HTML inside a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

When I try to add a button on a html table the table won't appear. On the last element of "ligne" `td class=ach`.

```js
function afficherCatalogue(livres){ 
    var ligne;
    for(var i in livres) {  
        ligne = '<tr>';
        ligne += '<td class=ref>' + Object.keys(livres[i])[0] + '</td>'; 
        ligne += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  
        ligne += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>'; 
        ligne += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  
        ligne += '<td class=ach>' + <button type="button"></button> + '</td>';
        ligne += '</tr>';

        document.getElementById('tbc').innerHTML += ligne;
    }
```

```html
<tbody id=tbc><!-- table to fill --></tbody>
```

I have to add a simple button.

Comment: What is the `livres` parameter supposed to be? Number, array, string? And if it is one of those, `for(var i in livres)` is not how you write a `for loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `livres` references an array of objects, you need to remove `tbody` from your table and create the `tbody` element with JavaScript using the `createElement()` method.

After creating the element, you can use a for loop to retrieved the required data from each object in the array and assign it to the `ligne` variable.

After looping through the objects, you can then populate the `tbody` element you just created with the retrieved data from the `ligne` variable using [innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property and then append the `tbody` element to your table using the [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method like this:

```js
/* JavaScript */
var table = document.getElementById("table");

function afficherCatalogue(livres){
  var ligne = "";  
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  
  tbody.setAttribute("id", "tbc");
  
  for(i = 0; i < livres.length; i++) {  
    ligne = '<tr>';
    ligne += '<td class=ref>' + Object.keys(livres[i])[0] + '</td>'; 
    ligne += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  
    ligne += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>'; 
    ligne += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';
    ligne += '<td class=ach>' + '<button type="button">Button ' + i + '</button>' + '</td>';
    ligne += '</tr>';

    tbody.innerHTML += ligne;

    table.appendChild(tbody);
  }
}

var data = [{First: "first", auteur: 100, titre: 200, prix: 300}, {Second: "second", auteur: 150, titre: 250, prix: 350}, {Third: "third", auteur: 200, titre: 300, prix: 400}]

afficherCatalogue(data);
```

```css
/* CSS */
table {
  text-align: center;
}
thead td {
  font-weight: 700;
}
td {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you ! that worked great. indeed creating tbody with js is better

Comment: @fryx Glad I could help mate. Cheers!!